# How to check whether the connection is established or not in java?

Tags: java, connection, urlconnection

I want to establish a connection using a url but i am getting IO exception because my server is not up . i want to check whether my connection is established or not how can i acheive this in java. here is my code

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(configurationManagement.getValue(url)).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401"); // Do as if you'rusing Firefox 3.6.3
            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

> i am getting IO exception because my server is not up . i want to check whether my connection is established or not how can i acheive this in java.

You *have* checked. You got the `IOException`. That told you. If you want to get it earlier in the piece, call `connect()` or `getResponseCode().` If `getResponseCode()` doesn't throw an IOException and returns 200, read the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right now (not straightworward). If you will be able to read from input stream (read some data, or block waiting for input) will mean that connection is up and running. Exception will be thrown otherwise.

You can always call `URLConnection#connect()` to explicitly connect to provided resource, and again if exception is not thrown, you got the connection.
 BTW `getInputStream` is calling `connect()` behind the scenes if you haven't do so before that call.

Refere to [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) for more informations.

Comment: yes i want to handle that exception i want to check if my connection is open then only read input stream

Comment: Than put everything in simple try catch block. It will be done automaticly

Answer (score -1):

By ping we can check the system status

```
String command = "ping -c 3 " + IP;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: That doesn't tell him whether the HTTP server he's trying to connect to is up, i.e. whether he can really establish a connection.